# Single word that encompasses backpacks, baskets, pockets, etc

Tags: word-request, nouns

What is a good, single word to describe any means of keeping and transporting items?

The word must describe: backpacks, baskets, pockets, purses and plastic bags. Bonus points if hands fit the definition.

I don't think most people would consider a pocket to be a *container* but I can't think of anything more general.

Comment: I would say "receptacle" or "vessel".

Comment: Maybe "carrier". Some are ships, some go on bicycle handlebars.

Comment: backpack is the only one you don't carry "in your hands".

Comment: @Lambie Pockets? Purses? 3/5 of these aren't carried in one's hands, barring a difference in interpretation.

Comment: In the UK, a 'purse' is almost invariably a smaller thing kept in a pocket or larger bag. Could have a zip, or for women, a clasp. Often used for coins.

Comment: @Micah, well, one does carry things in pockets and purses. Right? So, the odd-man out is backpack in that sense. My meaning was that the others involve the hands more directly. Yes, in AmE, we have change purses, too.